# Countdown timer counting too far

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, countdown

I am trying to make a game that tests how many times you can click on a div in a minute. I can not get my countdown to function properly. My countdown should stop at 0, but instead it keeps going after reaching 0. My code is below. Any ideas?

```js
let div = document.getElementById("div");
let score = document.querySelector("h3");
let time = document.querySelector("span");
var jsTime = 60;
var jsScore = 0;

alert("Click inside the box as many times as you can in one minute. \n Ready?");

var clicker = div.addEventListener("click", function() {
  jsScore++;
  score.innerHTML = jsScore;
}, 1);

var i = 60;

setInterval(function() {
  if (i > 1) {
    jsTime--;
    time.innerHTML = jsTime;
  } else {
    removeEventListener(clicker);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Click inside the box as many times as you can in one minute.</h1>

<br>

<div id="container">
  <h2>Time:</h2><span>60</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <h2>Score:</h2>
  <h3>0</h3>
</div>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're decreasing the `jsTime` as long as `i is > 1`, which it will always be, since you never decrease the value of `i`. I think you meant to use `jsTime` in the conditional instead. Renaming it to something that gives it some context may make it easier to follow. Ex `remainingTimeSeconds`. See the revised code below.

```
   let div = document.getElementById("div");
        let score = document.querySelector("h3");
        let time = document.querySelector("span");
        var jsTime = 60;
        var jsScore = 0;
        alert("Click inside the box as many times as you can in one minute. \n Ready?");

        var clicker = div.addEventListener("click", function() {
            jsScore++;
            score.innerHTML = jsScore;
        },1);



        setInterval(function() {
            // As long as there is time left, keep decreasing it, and update the time element's innerHTML with the new current time.
            if (jsTime > 1){
                jsTime--;
                time.innerHTML = jsTime;
            } else {
                removeEventListener(clicker);
            }
        },1000);
```